# Partition table on nother device

Tags: linux, arch-linux, partition, partition-table

I'm curious if it's possible to store disk partition tables on different device and load it from grub

**Edit:**
Lets say i have disk formated like this:
[image: disk with 3 partition and ~ 12gb unallocated at end]

normally post load mbr **(disk 1)** and starting up,
system sees only 3 partition and unallocated space

but im wonder if its possible to make different scenario.
Lets say I have data tables of this  disk which look like this:

[image: disk with 3 partition and ~ 454gb unallocated at beginning]
and what i wants to do here is load this alternative partition tables from another drive (this drive will also had grub installed on it)
instead of those which are on disk (without replacing them) and start os from it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, start different Linux installations from grub, or back up your partition table?

Comment: sorry, i added this question before i started looking for information about this i hope now it's more clear what i want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're trying to hide a second OS into what looks like unpartitioned space? Not a very secure method, as e.g. running `testdisk` on the disk will detect the partitions and offer to add them to the real partition table. I would expect any forensic tools to also quickly detect that the "unallocated space" seems to have some structured content within it.

But sure, it might pass a casual examination.

I don't think GRUB could do this easily, but if the external boot drive can also have the kernel and the initramfs file on it, then you could do it pretty easily within initramfs: create a table of mappings (basically a name + starting block number + length) for the hidden partitions, use `dmsetup create` to load the mappings, then have the initramfs mount e.g. `/dev/mapper/hidden_root` as a root filesystem, then let the boot proceed essentially normally, but mounting `/dev/mapper/hidden_other` and using `/dev/mapper/hidden_swap` as a swap partition if needed.

To load the mapping for each hidden partition, you would run a command like this:

```
dmsetup create <name> --table "0 <length in blocks> linear <disk major:minor> <first block #>"
```

`<disk major:minor>` would be the major and minor numbers of the disk device that contains the hidden partitions, e.g. `8:0` for /dev/sda.

If your first hidden partition was named `hidden_root`, the command for mapping it it would look something like this:

```
dmsetup create hidden_root --table "0 4236248 linear 8:0 952190894"
```

Essentially this means: "map a linear stretch of disk /dev/sda starting from block# 952190894 onwards, and present it as blocks 0..4236248 of /dev/mapper/hidden_root."

Even if you could have GRUB read an alternate partition table, you would have to do the above in initramfs anyway, because the Linux kernel won't rely on what the firmware tells it, but instead will read the partition table on its own to find any partitions.